# Cordova : Access last taken pictures from gallery (without picker)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to access to the last (3 or whatever) pictures taken from the phone gallery without opening any picker ?

I want to create my own very simple image picker for my Ionic (2) project.

I don't want the user to select images from the image picker of the cordova-plugin-camera, but to show him directly the last 3 images from his camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

Find a cordova plugin for iOS :

https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-camera-roll

It helps getting an URI of each photo presents in the camera roll. So we I can do my job with the first three ones...

Looking for something similar for Android now !